# How to return the ID of this span under a LI nodeObject using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have

```
<li>
<span id="foobar"> abc </span>
</li>
```

I now have `li` as an nodeObject. I could get `"LI"` by using `li.nodeName`.

Now how could I get `"foobar"` out of `li` which is an ID of a span inside it.

I tried:

```
 $node = li;
 alert($node>span.Id);
```

but not working, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
alert(li.firstElementChild.id);
```

or this...

```
alert(li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].id);
```

or this...

```
alert(li.children[0].id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will work:

```
var node = $('li');
alert(node.children('span').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tag selector along with id selector to select proper element so you can use below to select span with an id inside an li

```
$(li#foobar")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is very easy. Check this out:

```
var test = $("li span").attr("id");
alert(test);
```